# Adding suffix not working with sed and awk on macOS

Tags: macos, awk, sed, suffix

These are the contents of `t.txt`

```
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
```

I tried these commands to add a suffix to the end of the line:

```
$ cat t.txt | sed -e 's/$/-asdf/'
$ cat t.txt | awk '{ print $0 "-asdf" }'
```

The result in macOS:

```
-asdfFG
-asdfFG
-asdfFG
ABCDEFG-asdf
```

The result in Linux:

```
ABCDEFG-abcd
ABCDEFG-abcd
ABCDEFG-abcd
ABCDEFG-abcd
```

Why do I not get the same result in macOS?

Comment: can you add output of `cat -A t.txt` to question?

Comment: This smells like a case of `\r\n`. Use `dos2unix file` or in awk `sub(/\r/,"",$NF)` ro remove the `\r`.

Comment: try something like `cat t.txt | LC_ALL=C sed -e 's/$/-asdf/'` or `cat t.txt | sed -e 's/.*/&-asdf/'`

Comment: @Sundeep no such option for cat in macOS

Comment: @JamesBrown I'm working on macOS, no \r\n there.

Comment: @NeronLeVelu nothing works

Comment: and a `sed 's/[[:print:]]*/&-asdf/' t.txt` to avoid a piped cat and using only printable char ?

Comment: @Sean, what about `cat -e t.txt`?

Comment: To be 100% sure what each line contains use `head -2 file |od -t x1c` which afaik is available on mac. You can never be 100% sure that  your file does not contain \r which might have been there by file creator.

Comment: My bad! It has \r\n indeed. I wan't suspect that because I'm working solely on mac. Actually It was from 'torus view -e some > t.txt'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have carriage returns in your file. macOS Sierra, using built-in sed on an LF-only file:

```
mike ~ ❱❱❱ cat t.txt
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
mike ~ ❱❱❱ /usr/bin/sed -e 's/$/-asdf/' t.txt
ABCDEFG-asdf
ABCDEFG-asdf
ABCDEFG-asdf
ABCDEFG-asdf
```

Re-saved it with CRLF:

```
mike ~ ❱❱❱ /usr/bin/sed -e 's/$/-asdf/' t.txt
-asdfFG
-asdfFG
-asdfFG
-asdfFG
```

Comment: Same behavior on openbsd. I think awk of mac is same as openbsd. By the way my geany editor allows me to select line endings through a menu : LF (unix) - Windows (CRLF) and Classic Mac CR.

Comment: Yes, macOS uses all BSD utilities, and it causes no end of confusion! That said, I get the same behaviour with CRLF files using `gsed`.

Comment: I have Debian - FreeBSD (VM) and OpenBSD (VM) and all of them have available gawk in their repos. I suppose even mac has gawk. I still can not understand why most non Linux people refuse to use gnu tools when these tools are available for most of the distros out there.

Comment: I had to install gawk via MacPorts actually. Not built-in at all.

Comment: Built in is only at Debian and similar Linux Distros. Not built in on BSD also. But it is just few letters away.... :-)